# When I jumped from the list page to the details page, the url jumped, but the page did not display, and the prompt 'ZiXun' object is not iterable

Tags: django

I've tried adding "Read More" to the html. After clicking "Read More", the page shows that the path has jumped. Turned around, but the page does not display information. I hope that after clicking "Read More", I can jump to the `news.html` page and display the contents. I hope someone can help me.

news_list.html:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'news' zx.id %}">Read More</a>
```

news.html:

```
<div class="header">
<span><a href="{% url 'news' zx.id %}">{{ zx.zxname }}</a> </span>
<span>{{ zx.zxname }}</span>
</div>
<div class="">
{{ zx.zxblog | safe }}
</div>
```

views.py:

```
def news(request,zx_id):
    try:
        zixun=ZiXun.objects.get(id=zx_id)
        print('1------------------>')
        print(zixun)
        print(zx_id)
    except ZiXun.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render(request,'news.html',locals())
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace locals() with {'zx': zixun}. If that news view is being called then you template will render zx object from the context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after I changed it, this data still can't be passed to the HTML page. I wrote {{ zixun.zxname }} and {{ zixun.zxblog | safe }} in the html page.